# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: guild is a required argument that is missing

Tags: discord.py

i would like make a command for set permissions to all text channels, but i have a few difficulty to make this command

I've tried to many times but i not remember what i must
please help me, i need a code

**my code:**

```
@bot.command()
async def close_all(ctx, *, guild: discord.Guild):
    for chan in guild.channels:
      await guild.channels.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

**the error:**
`guild is a required argument that is missing.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing right now, is **requiring the guild as an argument for your command** so what the bot is actually looking for is a message

`close_all <guild>`

The `guild: discord.Guild` is a [Converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to guild, so somehow it should convert the string to a guild object. As this is not really possible, there is no way your command is going to work.

**Easy solution:** Just always use the guild the message has been sent in

```py
@bot.command()
async def close_all(ctx):
    for chan in ctx.guild.channels:
        await guild.channels.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

**More flexible solution:** An extra argument is passed to the function, which is the id of the guild where the command should be executed

```py
@bot.command()
async def close_all(ctx, guild_id: int):
    # finding the guild according to the id passed
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, ctx.bot.guilds)
    for chan in guild.channels:
        await guild.channels.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Comment: now it gives me an error with your second solution
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax: ` in `(lambda g.id == guild_id, ctx.bot.guilds)`

Comment: @FredtheCat Oh, my bad, the ":" after the "lambda" was missing. I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience but it's very important for me,
now the error is `guild_id is a required argument that is missing.`
and  in `g.id` undefined `g`

Comment: @FredtheCat No worries. So the first error was because you only wrote "close_all" instead of "close_all <id>" (you have to enter an id as an argument, as I said in my answer). The other error was my mistake, it's fixed now.

Comment: Yeah, Stackoverflow can be mean and condescending sometimes. I'm happy I was of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@bot.command()
async def close_all(ctx):
    for chan in ctx.guild.channels:
      await chan.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Looking at the error you're getting it seems to me like you're not passing a guild object. Also, your for-loop is not actually using it's index except for making sure it runs for a certain amount of times.

As long as the guild's permissions you're trying to change are the guild that you're sending this message in, this should work.